# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography' when using Buildroot on the STM32MP157D-DK1

Tags: linux, embedded, buildroot

I'm following the instructions per this doc: https://bootlin.com/blog/building-a-linux-system-for-the-stm32mp1-basic-system/ to build and deploy the Linux image for the STM32MP157D-DK1 board. However, I'm getting stuck with this error when running the `make` command:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/parallels/Projects/stm32mp1/buildroot/output/build/optee-os-custom/scripts/pem_to_pub_c.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/parallels/Projects/stm32mp1/buildroot/output/build/optee-os-custom/scripts/pem_to_pub_c.py", line 24, in main
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography'
```

I tried defining `BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON_CRYPTOGRAPHY` in the `.config` file but it still doesn't build. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Could you please use https://github.com/bootlin/buildroot-external-st instead of this blog post, which uses a quite old version of Buildroot? We now have much better stuff available at https://github.com/bootlin/buildroot-external-st.